# Alternate of Class.forName("XYZClass") in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create instance of “Class” Using “Reflection” in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462881/create-instance-of-class-using-reflection-in-javascript)

Java has `Class.forName("XYZClass")` to load class at run time. Is there any alternate for `Class.forName("XYZClass")` in JavaScript?

Comment: Actually I am trying to create object at run time. I have passed a class or function name say 'MyClass' to a function and that function will create object according to that name.

Comment: It looks like he's trying to load Javascript classes at runtime. But Javasript doesn't have classes...

Comment: And JavaScript is at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think you are trying to literally translate Java code to JavaScript rather than using idiomatic constructs (well, `Class.forName()` isn't idiomatic in Java as well). However, let's give it a try:

```
function XYZClass() {
    this.answer = 42;
}
```

This is your class. Normally you would create it using:

```
var xyz = new XYZClass();
```

With "*reflection*" in JavaScript this works:

```
var className = "XYZClass";
var xyz = new window[className]();
```

Comment: I did not understand your code properly, and I am getting error "TypeError: window[className] is not a constructor".

Comment: @gmuhammad: and does `new window.XYZClass()` work? Also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462881, it has a similar solution.

Comment: I got your point now, at first try XYZClass was not declared as global. Now I declared it as global and it's working now. And Now I got it why it's working, it's accessing class/function using window which is top level global variable. Thanx. :)